# react-native-smart-splash-screen android status-bar issue

Tags: android, react-native

I am using 
[react native smart splash screen](https://github.com/react-native-component/react-native-smart-splash-screen).

my question is

> is there any way to hide status-bar on splash screen in android ?

(its working fine in ios).

Comment: Please show your code or the example you're working with.

Answer (score 5):

> On MainActivity.java, just like that:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SplashScreen.show(this, true); // <- second parameter is true, to hide StatusBar
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

source: https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen/issues/105#issuecomment-401966983